# Rails js script runs too much times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a problem with **JavaScript** assets in rails 5.1, and I'm looking for solution. On one of my sub-pages in rails project i want to use `fullpage.js` from.

This git: [alvarotrigo](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#fullpagejs)

I'm initialising js with this function

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
     $('#fullpage').fullpage();
 });
```

On first run it looks as it should, but when i select  another sub page and then came back to `fullpage.js` it run script one more time and console shows error that `fullpage.js` has been already loaded (and don't work) it seems that turbo links triggers loading one more time.

Is there any solution for this problem?

I'm just started working with webdev.

Comment: That's what `turbolinks:load` does. You probably need one of the "classic" ways of adding JS to page load, as described at https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior